# ffmpeg connection reset by peer

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I have a problem when using ffmpeg:

quite often my clients will have slightly dodgy internet connections but they subscribe to a service which is designed to record a stream that they are hosting, and record it for hosting on something like a wordpress site.

ffmpeg is called by a python script.  I would like, ideally, to know if ffmpeg will throw an exception or return a value that can be accessed by the python script and used as a variable to determine if there was a problem recording the audio.

at the moment python calls ffmpeg using:

```
os.system('ffmpeg -i [stream address] -t 1:00 -acodec copy ')
```

when I simulate a connection loss (turning off the NIC on the virtual machine) ffmpeg prints to the terminal

```
Connection reset by peer
```

Comment: is there a return value?

Comment: Not sure where to find the return Value from ffmpeg.  sorry rogerdpack

Answer (score 1):

So not a direct answer, but a suitable method for getting the desired response, written in pseudocode in order to make it easily understandable:

```
finishTime = timeNow + recordingDuration
call RecordFunction (source, destination, finishTime)

def RecordFunction (source, destination, finishTime):

    calculate recording duration with simple arithmetic

    ffString([Build the ffrecording strin])
    run.commandLine(ffstring)
    timeLeft = finishTime - timNow
    if timeLeft > tollerance:
        call RecordFunction(source, destination, finishTime)
```

optionally one can check the ffmpeg log and pass that to a log file.  Or one can set a limit on the number of disconnects occurring.

Answer (score 1):

As per documentation of os.system:

"On Unix, **the return value is the exit status of the process** encoded in the format specified for wait(). Note that POSIX does not specify the meaning of the return value of the C system() function, so the return value of the Python function is system-dependent."